# How to visualize the interior of a complicated 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization

I have an external data file (can be downloaded here: [link 1](http://www.mediafire.com/view/jofdbfob6pi1f29/data_3d.out) or [link 2](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/3c69e895)) which contains a dense grid of initial condition in the (x,y,z) space. I read it with Mathematica and plot these initial conditions with different colors according to some specific properties

```
m = Import["data_3d.out", "Table"];

getColor[m_List, i_Integer] := 
Module[{s = m[[i, 6]]}, 
Which[s == 0, Black, s == 1, Red, s == 2, Darker[Green], s == 3, 
Brown, s == 4, Blue, s == 5, Orange, s == 6, Cyan, s == 7, 
Magenta, s == 8, Yellow, True, White]];

data = Table[{PointSize[0.004], getColor[m, i], 
Point[{m[[i, 1]], m[[i, 2]], m[[i, 3]]}]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}];

P0 = Graphics3D[data, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
PlotRange -> 6, ImageSize -> 550]
```

and here is the output

[image]

We observe, that several color patterns appear but we can see only the surface of the three-dimensional grid. So, the question:

Is there a way to penetrate inside the 3d surface and visualize how these color patterns are? Any suggestions?

Please, us the original data file for testing. I think, generating simpler but random 3d grids in this case, could be very illusive since all the story is about the color patterns that appear and obviously cannot be replicated randomly.

**EDIT**

A second working link for retrieving the data file is added.

Comment: Mediafire isn't a good choice for sharing info. Anyway, your request about using your datafile doesn't sound right. Since you're asking for _" a way to penetrate inside the 3d surface"_, any 3D point set will do as an example

Comment: @belisarius But any 3D point set does not have the properties of my datafile. The purpose is to find a way to visualize the color patterns inside the surface however these patterns are not random!

Comment: @belisarius Any particular reason why Mediafire is not a good choice?! So far, no problems encountered.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/p0adW.png

Comment: @belisarius Oops! Probably maintenance ... Any alternatives? Does StackExchange have its own repository for files?

Comment: Consider moving the view point to the inside the data cluster. See docs on [ViewPoint](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewPoint.html)

Comment: From the inside it looks like it has some fractal structure.  I usually use either dropbox or ge.tt for file uploads.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A tomographic approach:

```
m = Import["http://www.datafilehost.com/get.php?file=3c69e895", "Data"];

getColor[s_List] := 
  Replace[s, {0 -> Black, 1 -> Red, 2 -> Darker[Green], 3 -> Brown, 
    4 -> Blue, 5 -> Orange, 6 -> Cyan, 7 -> Magenta, 
    8 -> Yellow, _ -> White}, 1];

nfx = Nearest[m[[All, 1]] -> m];

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.004], 
   Point[#[[All, 1 ;; 3]], VertexColors -> getColor[#[[All, 6]]]] &@ nfx[x0]},
  Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> 6, ImageSize -> 350],
 {x0, Min[m[[All, 1]]], Max[m[[All, 1]]]}
 ]
```

[image: Manipulate output]

Other ways of slicing:

```
nfy = Nearest[m[[All, 2]] -> m];
nfz = Nearest[m[[All, 3]] -> m];
```

---

In response to a comment, here is a static approach:

```
xlist = Range[0, 5, 1]

Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.004], 
  Point[#[[All, 1 ;; 3]], VertexColors -> getColor[#[[All, 6]]]] &@
   Flatten[nfx /@ xlist, 1]}, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> 6, ImageSize -> 350]

(* {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Amazing!!! Is it possible to include inside the 3d space several slices, let's say for x = {0,1,2,3,4,5}? No manipulation, just a static graphic for several slices.

Comment: Many many thanks!

Answer (score 11):

One easy, although not beautiful way relies on the properties of 3D graphics. When you look how the [simulated camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) works, then you see that only the volume between near- and farplane is rendered. If you put your near plane in the distance, everything which is too close is cut.

In *Mathematica* this can be be adjusted using the [`ViewRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewRange.html) option of `Graphics3D`. Here is a small example:

```
data = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Triceratops"}, "VertexData"];
With[{gr = 
   Graphics3D[{{Hue[#3], Sphere[{##}, .2]} & @@@ data}, 
    SphericalRegion -> True]},
 Manipulate[
  Show[gr, ViewPoint -> {0, -1, .5}, 
   ViewRange -> {nearPlane, farPlane}],
  {nearPlane, 4, 10},
  {{farPlane, 15}, 5, 15}
  ]
 ]
```

Full graphics

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Cut graphics

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Poor decapitated Triceratops! Well, apparently your 3d surface is haul inside, while mine is not!

Comment: Why don't you give a shot using my data? (use the second link)

Comment: [No animal were harmed in the making of this answer](http://blogartandhumanities.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/no-animals-were-harmed.jpg?w=300&h=262)

Comment: @belisarius Hey, leave me out of this, ok?

Comment: @rm-rf A decapitated frog? That's quite an idea

Answer (score 8):

There are couple other ways to visualize 3D images, one of which is new in V10.  (*Note:* The links to the original data are no longer valid.)

The new features, [`ClipPlanes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html) and [`IntervalSlider`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalSlider.html), are useful here.  Something like this was demonstrated at WTC 2014.

```
knee = Raster3D[
   RawArray["Byte", 
    ImageData[ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "MRknee"}], "Byte"]],
    {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}}, {0, 255}, 
   ColorFunction -> "GrayLevelOpacity"];

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[knee, 
  ClipPlanes -> {{0, 1, 0, -y[[1]]}, {0, -1, 0, y[[2]]}}, 
  Axes -> True],
 {{y, {-1, 1}}, -1, 1, IntervalSlider}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[`ClipRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipRange.html) was introduce in V9 for 3D images.

```
Image3D[ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "MRknee"}], ClipRange -> {All, {0, 60}, All}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]