# Only show part of a cube below an intersecting plane

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry, geometry, intersection

I plot a cube and a plane. I just want to show the part below the plane.

The code:

```
p2 = Animate[
Show[{Graphics3D[Cuboid[{2, -2, -1}, {-2, 2, 3}], Boxed -> False], 
ContourPlot3D[{z - t y - t x == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 
  3}, {z, -7, 7}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, 
    x^2 + y^2 - r^2 - z + t y + t x]}, Mesh -> False, 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]], 
 Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> 400]}], {{t, -0}, -3, 3}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Closely related: [37025](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37025/5478)

Comment: I'd say a duplicate. That's why I'm leaving this here:  `Manipulate[
     Graphics3D[Cuboid[{2, -2, -1}, {-2, 2, 3}], Boxed -> False, 
      ClipPlanes -> {-{-t, -t, 1, 0}}], {{t, -0}, -3, 3}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`ClipPlanes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html) and [`ClipPlanesStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanesStyle.html)

```
Animate[Graphics3D[Cuboid[{2, -2, -1}, {-2, 2, 3}], 
  ClipPlanes -> -{-t, -t, 1, 0}, Boxed -> False, 
  ClipPlanesStyle -> 
   Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]
  ], {{t, -0}, -3, 3}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
p2 = Animate[Show[{
    RegionPlot3D[
     And[-2 < x < 2, -2 < y < 2, -1 < z < 3, z - t y - t x < 0], 
        {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}
        ],
    ContourPlot3D[{z - t y - t x == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 
      3}, {z, -7, 7}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, 
        x^2 + y^2 - r^2 - z + t y + t x]}, Mesh -> False, 
     ContourStyle -> 
      Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]], 
     Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
     ImageSize -> 400]}], {{t, -0}, -3, 3}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is just an extended comment.

The corners that you used to define the `Cuboid` do not define a valid region.

While Cuboid[{2, -2, -1}, {-2, 2, 3}] and Cuboid[{-2, -2, -1}, {2, 2, 3}] fill the same space, Mathematica only considers the second `Cuboid` to be a valid region.

```
RegionQ /@ {
  Cuboid[{2, -2, -1}, {-2, 2, 3}],
  Cuboid[{-2, -2, -1}, {2, 2, 3}]}
```

> {False, True}

```
RegionMember[
 Cuboid[{-2, -2, -1}, {2, 2, 3}],
 {x, y, z}]
```

> -2 <= x <= 2 && -2 <= y <= 2 && -1 <= z <= 3

Comment: Interesting observation.